# jQuery Countdown browsers compatibility

Tags: jquery, ios, firefox, safari, countdown

I have this script which works fine on Chrome, Opera and Edge. But when I try this with Firefox, Safari for Mac or Safari for iOS the values of the countdown are all "NaN".

Moreover, I have not any error in the debug console so I don't know what could be the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/jossday/xzsdn9nn/1/

Maybe the date format is involved ?

```
targetTime: new Date('2016-04-14, 00:00:00'),
```

Thanks to help.

EDIT : We have to convert the date format like (2016,3,14,0,0,0).

Here's a way to do this :

```
var dateFin = '2016-04-14 00:00:00';
var first_part = dateFin.split(" ")[0],
year = first_part.split("-")[0],
month =  first_part.split("-")[1];
if(month.indexOf("0")==0){
  month = month.split("0")[1];
}
month = month-1;
var day =  first_part.split("-")[2];
if(day.indexOf("0")==0){
  day = day.split("0")[1];
}
var last_part = dateFin.split(" ")[1],
hour = last_part.split(":")[0],
minute = last_part.split(":")[1],
seconds = last_part.split(":")[2];

var dateFormat = new Date (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);
```

Comment: You need to pass relevant date format. AZt least this one is more relevant: `new Date(2016,3,14,0,0,0)`

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot. I get this date from PHP so is there any way to convert '2016-04-14, 00:00:00' into 2016,3,14,0,0,0 in JS ?